# MAMP 5.0.5 on Windows : PHP 8.1.0 doesn't work

Tags: php, windows, mamp, startup

I just migrated my old MAMP version on Windows. I uninstalled properly MAMP 4.2.0 and installed MAMP 5.0.5. I went into the MAMP preferences / PHP tab and changed from PHP version 8.0.1 to version 8.1.0.
After starting the servers, I tried to open the WebStart page and I got a blank screen with lot of errors in php_errors.log file like : "PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library *.dll". The DLL are all in the specified directory.

If I change to PHP 8.0.1, everything works fine.

I looked at all the log files and tried PHP 8.0.1 which works fine. Trying again with PHP 8.1.0 leads to the same errors.

Comment: you may need to change your environment variables for php to the newest one

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My specific problem is that PHP 8.1.0 is not running correctly with MAMP 5.0.5 on Windows. And I would like it to run correctly.
I have no environment variable defined at the OS level. I can see a configuration in Apache http.conf :
*PHPIniDir "C:\MAMP\conf\php8.1.0\php.ini"
LoadModule php_module "C:\MAMP\bin\php\php8.1.0\php8apache2_4.dll"*
I can't find any other configuration. MAMP should handle the change between PHP 8.0.1 and PHP 8.1.0.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found an old php installation, apart of MAMP on my PC, which was conflicting MAMP. I desinstalled it and now it works fine.
Thank you mmh4all for your hint.